# Timer doesn't stop with the if else

Tags: java, timer, timertask

```
public static void randomN () {
    int requestTime = 2;
    if(requestTime > 0) {
      requestTime--;  
      myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              public void run() {
                int randomx = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
                int randomy = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
                System.out.println("Requests" + "X : " + randomx + " Y: " + randomy);
              }
      }, 0, 1000);
    } else {
          myTimer.cancel();
          myTimer.purge();
    } 
}
```

I want my timer to do the task inside public void run() { ... } and do it every seconds for 2 seconds. But this code doesn't work properly.

Comment: Is this static method called from different threads?

Comment: Are you sure that you call `randomN()` at least three times?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: Why would I call randomN() three times? I called randomN() in public static void main if that's what you ask.

Comment: implements your own `TimeTask` with a countdown to 3?

Answer (score 1):

in this code:

```
public static void randomN () {
    int requestTime = 2;
    if(requestTime > 0) { //..
```

your requestTime will always be 2 at the time of if statement, no matter how many times you call the method. I guess you want

```
static int requestTime = 2;
public static void randomN () {
    if(requestTime > 0) { //..
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't stop, because you have decremented `requestTime` only once before the `Timer` starts. The timer only execute the code inside `run()` method repeatedly with the period you have given. So if you want to update `requestTime` you will have to do it in the `run()` method.

```
        final int requestTime = 2; 
        final Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         int aRequestTime = requestTime; 
           @Override
           public void run() {
               if(aRequestTime > 0)
               {
                   aRequestTime--;
               }

               else timer.cancel();
           }
       }, 0, 2000);
```

Try declare your `Timer` and `requestTime` in your `Class` context instead of function to get rid of the `final` variable. As you know local inner class: `Anonymous` class won't change the local variable.

Comment: what about visibility of variables?

Comment: I did point that out at the end of my answer i guess. As i have used `aRequestTime` to read `requestTime` first and updated it.

Comment: I need to read more about java memory threading. Question was about should `timer` variable be marked with `volatile`  keyword?

Comment: `volatile` keyword is used as an indicator to Java compiler and  Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory which reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. Although OP hasn't specified whither his program is in multi-threading environment or not: my code above actually assumes that the `timer` is local to the `randomN` function (that is the reason of using `final` actually) So no worries for multi-thread inference here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cancel the timer from inside the task after two executions and change the last parameter of `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask,long,long)` to 2000 milliseconds. And probably the second as well, if you want it to start after 2 seconds as well.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    private int counter = 2;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        counter--;
        if(counter >= 0)
            System.out.println(counter + " more ticks to go.");
        else
            timer.cancel();
    }
}, 0, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify code to next:

```
private static volatile Timer myTimer = new Timer();
private static volatile int runTimes = 0;

public static void randomN () {
  myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

          public void run() {
            runTimes++;

            printRandomXY();
            cancelTimerIfRunTwice();
          }
  }, 0, 1000);
}

private static void printRandomXY() {
   int randomx = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
   int randomy = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
   System.out.println("Requests" + "X : " + randomx + " Y: " + randomy);
}

private static void cancelTimerIfRunTwice() {
   if (runTimes == 2) {
       myTimer.cancel();
       myTimer.purge();
   }
}
```

Comment: I should consider `volatile` more often, it's sometimes very handy. Thanks for reminding me of that.

Comment: It is better to use java concurrent